# no implementation of __fpclassify in armhf

Tags: raspberry-pi, arm, cross-compiling, libc, libm

I'm cross-compiling for Raspberry Pi 4B using ARM's [10.3-2021.07 GCC toolchain](https://developer.arm.com/tools-and-software/open-source-software/developer-tools/gnu-toolchain/gnu-a) (specifically [this](https://developer.arm.com/-/media/Files/downloads/gnu-a/10.3-2021.07/binrel/gcc-arm-10.3-2021.07-x86_64-arm-none-linux-gnueabihf.tar.asc) file uncompressed into `ARMGCC`). I'm also using the latest Raspberry OS [image](https://downloads.raspberrypi.org/raspios_lite_armhf/images/raspios_lite_armhf-2021-05-28/2021-05-07-raspios-buster-armhf-lite.zip) as sysroot (loop-mounted into `RPISYSROOT`). The host is an Ubuntu Xenial VM on a Windows host.

When using this compilation line (edited for readability, `CFLAGS` inspired by the Pi's `/proc/cpuinfo`, [gentoo](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Safe_CFLAGS#ARMv8-A.2FBCM2837) and [GNU](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/ARM-Options.html)):

```
${ARMGCC}/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabihf-g++ -std=c++11 \
-v -w -fexceptions -fpermissive --sysroot=$RPISYSROOT \
-pipe -mcpu=cortex-a72 -mfpu=neon-vfpv4 -mfloat-abi=hard -g \
-I . -I .. -I libA/include -I libB/include \
-I ${ARMGCC}/arm-none-linux-gnueabihf/libc/usr/include \
-I ${RPISYSROOT}/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf \
-c file.cpp -o obj/debug/file.o
```

I get the following error:

```
$ARMGCC/arm-none-linux-gnueabihf/libc/usr/include/bits/mathcalls-helper-functions.h:20:24: error: ‘__fpclassify’ has not been declared
   20 | __MATHDECL_ALIAS (int, __fpclassify,, (_Mdouble_ __value), fpclassify)
      |                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I see uses of `__fpclassify` in `ARMGCC`, `RPISYSROOT` and Raspberry Pi's [tools](https://github.com/raspberrypi/tools) git repo and they seem to be all iterations of the same files:

```
usr/include/math.h
usr/include/bits/mathcalls-helper-functions.h
```

(paths may vary slightly). However, none of these provide declarations or implementations of `__fpclassify`. This seems to come from `libm` which, I think, has been a part of `libc` for a while now. I've already installed [libc](https://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/g/glibc/libc6-dev_2.31-13%2Brpi1_armhf.deb) onto `RPISYSROOT`.
The only implementation I've found is from [uCLibc](https://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/u/uclibc/uclibc-source_1.0.35-1_all.deb) but I don't think mixing libc implementations is a good idea.

Also, since the Raspberry Pi is armhf, should I be seeing these errors?

Comment: If it is provided by `libm`, you may need to link against it using `-lm` in your command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is a mixing of the two sets of headers, those of the build chain (`ARMGCC`) and those of the specified system root (`RPISYSROOT`). In particular, presuming a `file.cpp` which looks something like:

```
#include <cmath>

void function(void) {}
```

your compilation command will perform the following nested includes:

- `${ARMGCC}/arm-none-linux-gnueabihf/include/c++/10.3.1/cmath`
- `${RPISYSROOT}/usr/include/math.h`
- `${ARMGCC}/arm-none-linux-gnueabihf/libc/usr/include/bits/mathcalls-helper-functions.h`

The specific error you are receiving (mentioning `__fpclassify`) is a bit misleading, because what is most relevantly undefined at that point is the `__MATHDECL_ALIAS` function-like macro, which is defined in `${ARMGCC}/arm-none-linux-gnueabihf/libc/usr/include/math.h`.

If you look at the same file under `RPISYSROOT`, you can see that it uses `__MATHDECL_1` instead:

```
/* Classify given number.  */
__MATHDECL_1 (int, __fpclassify,, (_Mdouble_ __value))
     __attribute__ ((__const__));
```

which is defined in `${RPISYSROOT}/usr/include/math.h`.

So what you need to do is ensure that `${RPISYSROOT}/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf/bits/mathcalls-helper-functions.h` is included instead of the `ARMGCC` counterpart, which you can do by changing the order of includes in your compilation command. Reducing your command to its essentials, we have:

```
${ARMGCC}/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabihf-g++ \
  --sysroot=${RPISYSROOT} \
  -I ${ARMGCC}/arm-none-linux-gnueabihf/libc/usr/include \
  -I ${RPISYSROOT}/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf \
  -c file.cpp \
  -o obj/debug/file.o
```

which fails as above. Changing this to:

```
${ARMGCC}/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabihf-g++ \
  --sysroot=${RPISYSROOT} \
  -I ${RPISYSROOT}/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf \
  -I ${ARMGCC}/arm-none-linux-gnueabihf/libc/usr/include \
  -c file.cpp \
  -o obj/debug/file.o
```

compiles successfully.

In fact, for this case we can remove the explicit reference to any `ARMGCC` includes, with the following:

```
${ARMGCC}/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabihf-g++ \
  --sysroot=${RPISYSROOT} \
  -I ${RPISYSROOT}/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf \
  -c file.cpp \
  -o obj/debug/file.o
```

which also compiles.

Comment: I've [solved](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69343450/1831722) this by using Raspberry Pi's toolchain together with a Raspbian sysroot.